# Running artisan code in SSH Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, ssh

Every time I insert the code artisan in SSH (eg. php artisan config:clear) it says the PHP version of the Cpanel is 5.3, but I inserted a code in htaccess to change it to 5.5. Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the right PHP for Laravel 5.2. 
I think it require **PHP 5.5**

I would suggest go into C Panel, and select the **PHP 5.5**.

More details see : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#laravel-5.2

Comment: It means the code that inserted in htaccess to change it to 5.5 is not working. Why the project is error free when I'm browsing it?